# How to load a script to ghci?

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting learning Haskell, and having a hard time understanding the 'flow' of a Haskell program.

For example in Python, I can write a script, load it to the interpreter and see the results:

```py
def cube(x):
    return x*x*x

print cube(1)
print cube(2)
print cube(cube(5))
# etc...
```

In Haskell I can do this:

```hs
cube x = x*x*x
main = print (cube 5)
```

Load it with `runhaskell` and it will print `125`.
Or I could use `ghci` and manually type all functions I want to test

But what I want is to use my text editor , write a couple of functions , a few tests , and have Haskell print back some results:

```hs
-- Compile this part
cube x = x*x*x

-- evaluate this part:
cube 1
cube 2
cube (cube 3)
--etc..
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cube x = x*x*x

main = do
    print $ cube 1
    print $ cube 2
    print $ cube (cube 3)
```

```
$ ghci cube.hs
...
ghci> main
```

See the [GHCI user guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci.html).

---

I also highly recommend checking out the [QuickCheck](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/testing-and-quality-assurance.html) library.

You'll be amazed at how awesome testing can be with it.

Comment: You can also use :l ( or :load)  if your ghci is already running, which mine usually is.

Comment: It works thanks :) need to check what those '$' do ! btw: is it possible to load , and evaluate main from the command line ? ex: ghci cube :run main !

Comment: @andsoa [this](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%24) will save you some minutes of hard googling :)

Comment: `$` eliminates the need for putting parentheses around the last argument of a function application when it would otherwise need them.  It makes your code look less like lisp!

Comment: @andsoa: Main is just an ordinary value, so you can just type `main` at the GHCi prompt.  You can also use `:main` to run `main`, and you can pass it command-line arguments that way: `:main arg1 ... argN`.  Another way to set command-line arguments is to use `:set args arg1 ... argN`.  For more, see [Section 2.7 of the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html).

Answer (score 14):

Very possible!

```
$ ghci
> :l filename.hs
```

That will load the file, and then you can use the functions directly.

```
> :r
```

That will cause the file to be reloaded after you make an edit. No need to mention the file, it will reload whatever the last one you loaded was. This also will work if you do `ghci filename.hs` initially instead of `:l`.

Answer (score 4):

To load a Haskell source file into GHCi, use the `:load` command

[cf Loading source file in Haskell documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html)